# Overkill or good application of normalization to create parent table just to associate a collection of children

Tags: sql-server-2016, normalization

I have a situation where I need to keep a group of detail rows together but where the "parent" has no additional attributes and the "children" have no purpose on their own. I started with the typical (to me) approach

```
GroupOfSomething
    Id

SomethingDetail
    Id
    GroupOfSomethingId (FK)
    LookupToAnotherTable (FK)
    SomethingElse
```

In the above, Id is PK of say INT. Wondering if something like the below with just the one table rather than the parent/child relationship is more appropriate (GroupId could be a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

```
GroupOfSomethings
    GroupId
    Id
    LookupToAnotherTable (FK)
    SomethingElse
```

In an effort to clarify, this is for something like an accounting system. The `Somethings` are FKs to accounts. There's going to be a collection of these accounts that the users will then link with one or more vendors. At the level that the vendor and collection of accounts are linked, there's additional metadata. Then *that* relationship will be the parent to yet another 1:many collection and to additional 1:1 and 1:many related entities. So it ends up looking something like below (with the original PK/FK structure, without defining what all the other FK tables are)

```
GroupOfAccounts
    Id (PK)

GroupOfAccountDetail
    Id (PK)
    GroupOfAccountId (FK)
    AccountId (FK)

VendorGroupOfAccountInfo
    Id (PK)
    VendorId (FK)
    GroupOfAccountId (FK)

VendorGroupOfAccountInfoAdditionalDetail
    Id (PK)
    VendorGroupOfAccountInfoId (FK)
    FeeStructureId (FK)
    StateId (FK)


VendorGroupOfAccountRates
    Id (PK)
    GroupOfAccountDetail (FK)
    RatePercentage
    EffectiveDate

...
```

Comment: Reorganizing designs for subtypes is not DB normalization in either of its senses of to a 1NF or to a higher NF. Normalization to higher NFs replaces a table by projections of it that natural join back to it.  "Normalization" with no qualifiers doesn't mean anything in particular. What do you mean by "normalization"? What do you think this post has to do with normalization?

Comment: @philipxy - apologies if I'm not using "normalization" 100% correctly. I'm a self-taught (apparently poorly...) software developer generalist, not a specialist in database design. My understanding of normalization and use in the question was around the concern of not duplicating data (in this case the group id) and towards J.D.'s point about meta-data at the group level (for which there is none right now)

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. If you don't know what the word means then just don't use it. And replacing/augmenting subrows by ids & splitting into tables for subtypes  aren't normalization. DB normalization to higher NFs replaces a table by projections of it that natural join back to it. Normalization to a 1NF involves removing table-valued columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to believe there's no meaningful associated meta-data with the `GroupOfSomething`s, besides the `Id`. But if that's all there is to it, and you don't have **any** business logic dependent on it (e.g. sorting the rows by `GroupOfSomethingId`), besides just `SELECT`ing certain groups of rows at a time, then I can't think of a great reason to have the `GroupOfSomething` table.

The only good reason I can think of is if you wanted to implement data integrity such that a row added to the `SomethingDetail` table can only be added to an existing valid group. The distinct list foreign keyed in the `GroupOfSomething` table ensures only a valid `GroupOfSomethingId` is used in the `SomethingDetail` table.

Comment: at the level I'm showing, there really isn't much more metadata, maybe an argument for Description or the like. Once that ```GroupOfSomethings``` is created, there are other downstream tables that will reference it where there's more metadata.

Comment: @CaseyR Yes, that would be one example, and then it would at least by meaningful to a human. Aside from that, there's no business logic, such as sorting, dependent on it?

Comment: No, not really - I updated the question with more details but unfortunately there's no real "description" that makes sense at that level other than to say something to the effect of "collection of account a,b,c" vs "collection of account a,b,d"

Comment: @CaseyR I understand your schema now. There's alternative implementations to linking the the collection of accounts to vendors as well, but I think your design is equally fine. Aside from all of that, as my answer mentions, the only other use case for having the separate table for the unique collection `ID` list would be if you needed data integrity for only valid pre-existing groups to be used.